# Problem using Ajax function with Bootstrap Validation

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, ajaxform, bootstrap-validate

I am encountering issues with my Ajax function combining it with Bootstrap validation. I guess it could be an issue with the form call in the Ajax function.

The email is properly sent as per PHP file, but not with Ajax function. I don't receive any error, but the Ajax call is ignored.

Do I have to redefine the form in the Ajax function ?

```js
// Bootstrap forms validation
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                form.querySelector(".form-control:invalid").focus();
                event.preventDefault()
                event.stopPropagation()
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        form.find(":submit").html("Sending...").prop('disabled', true);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        $(".toast").addClass('bg-danger');
                        $(".toast-body").text(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
                        $(".toast").toast("show");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success === true) {
                            form.removeClass('was-validated').trigger("reset");
                            $(".toast").addClass('bg-success');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".toast").addClass('bg-danger');
                        }
                        $(".toast-body").text(data.message);
                        $(".toast").toast("show");
                    }
                });
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/inc/contact.php" autocomplete="off" class="contact card-body needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname"
                    placeholder="firstname" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname"
                    placeholder="Lastname" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                    placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
                    required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"
                    placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject"
                    placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30"
                    rows="4" placeholder="Create a message here" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Send <i
                                class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="small mb-0 mt-0">By clicking this button, you agree to the <a
                            href="" rel="nofollow">terms and
                            conditions</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add more information? Some HTML code and also what error are you getting in console? It might help in better understanding the issue.

Comment: Added code snippet, maybe easier :)

Comment: @20cnts, I think you should also add `event.preventDefault()` statement into the else statement block.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of observations and a working solution

1. A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
   Move the event listener inside the $(document).ready(function() {/**/});
2. Include `event.preventDefault()` inside the `else` block in order to cancel the submission before executing the else block.

Here is the solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    submitForm();
});

function submitForm() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                form.querySelector(".form-control:invalid").focus();
                event.preventDefault()
                event.stopPropagation()
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        form.find(":submit").html("Sending...").prop('disabled', true);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        $(".toast").addClass('bg-danger');
                        $(".toast-body").text(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
                        $(".toast").toast("show");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success === true) {
                            form.removeClass('was-validated').trigger("reset");
                            $(".toast").addClass('bg-success');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".toast").addClass('bg-danger');
                        }
                        $(".toast-body").text(data.message);
                        $(".toast").toast("show");
                    }
                });
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't thought about the document.ready function(). However, I still have an issue : , the console is returning this : Uncaught TypeError: form.attr is not a function

Comment: @20cnts Didn't the above code work ?
Copy paste the above code and replace the your existing code.